magic keyboard help: 'e' and spacebar not working
I'm experiencing an issue with my Apple Magic Keyboard where the 'e' key and the spacebar as they don't function when pressed.
This problem persists on macOS 14.4.1, despite thorough cleaning of the keyboard and updating the software. Importantly, this issue does not occur with the built-in keyboard of my MacBook (Apple M3 Max) or older wireless mac keyboard.
What could be causing these specific keys to only work with Shift, and how can I address this problem?



Does the problem follow the keyboard to another computer?  Are you running the keyboard cabled, or Bluetooth?  Are you running any particular key remapping software?  Have you altered the build in key mapping file(s)?  When you shift these keys, do you get upper-case?

Boot into Safe Mode or Recovery. Does the issue continue to manifest?

You flagged all the comments as no longer needed. Usually we delete comments only after the clarifications asked for have been provided.

@nohillside, I think I addressed all of those messages. 1. with another old keyboard (bluetooth) all work with "shift E and SPACE work. 3. I didn't do any remapping to the keyboard.

@Allan safe mode didn't work either.
